# Why isn't this compiling? Cannot convert from 'X?' to 'X'

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I'm facing an unexpected issue (or is this the expected behaviour?). The following code is not compling and it's giving me the error:

`CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long?' to 'long'`

```cs
public static void Add(long? ticks)
{
    if (ticks != null)
    {
        new DateTime(ticks);
    }
}
```

Comment: `new DateTime(ticks.Value)`

Comment: You can widen from `long` to `long?`, but you can't narrow from `long?` to `long`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Well you *can* narrow that way, but you have to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no implicit conversion from `Nullable<T>` to `T` - you can do it explicitly via a cast, e.g. `new DateTime((long) ticks)`, or use the `Value` property, e.g. `new DateTime(ticks.Value)`.

As an alternative that I'd generally prefer now, you can use pattern matching from C# 7 to make it slightly simpler, extracting the non-null value in the same step where you check that it *is* non-null:

```cs
public static void Add(long? ticks)
{
    // This will match if ticks is non-null, and assign the value
    // into the newly-introduced variable "actualTicks"
    if (ticks is long actualTicks)
    {
        var dt = new DateTime(actualTicks);
        // Presumably use dt here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implicitly widen from `long` to `long?`, but you can't implicitly narrow from `long?` to `long`.

You need to do this:

```
public static void Add(long? ticks)
{
    if (ticks != null)
    {
        new DateTime(ticks.Value);  // or (long)ticks
    }
}
```